# Xamarin Tools for Visual Studio: Almost unusably slow

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, f#, resharper

I'm wondering if there are any workarounds for this issue, as I am plagued by frequent crashes -- though it isn't clear whether the crashes are caused by Resharper, Xamarin Tools or the mixture of C# and F# projects.

When I restart Visual Studio and load a solution containing Xamarin Forms projects, the entire display locks up. After one to three minutes, I get a pop-up saying that an update for Xamarin for Visual Studio is available (Clicking on the pop-up has no effect, so I'm assuming this is a false positive). A few seconds after that, it attempts to connect to my Mac, which is often unsuccessful as I work on my laptop and that connection is only available when I'm at home.

Only when the connection to the Mac has failed am I able to interact with Visual Studio, and then, about 30% of the time, attempting to build, clean or rebulid simply results in a pop-up saying "The operation could not be completed". The only way to fix that is to restart Visual Studio, causing the whole grinding process to restart again.

Xamarin themselves have referred me to these forums. Obviously this is not a pure software question, so I'll try to distill this into specific answerable questions.

1. Is there a way to prevent the false positive that tells me a new version of Xamarin for Visual Studio is available when it clearly isn't?
2. Is there a setting that I can use in order to opt in to connecting to the Mac, rather than attempting to make a connection and killing startup time when I know in advance that the connection will not be made?
3. Has the build problem "This operation could not be completed" been reported anywhere? I haven't found any instances of this problem related to Xamarin or Resharper. But it is frequent.

Comment: "*Xamarin themselves have referred me to these forums.*" They were wrong to do so. This is a programming Q&A site, not a software support forum.

Answer (score 1):

1. Does this consistently happen? We've had this problem over the years, but it's gotten much better. Make sure all your machines are synced with the latest Stable update. If on Beta/Alpha, this is typical as we push builds often. The strange part is that you say it's trying to update Xamarin Studio, we actually don't ship Xamarin Studio for Windows anymore: https://www.xamarin.com/faq#xpq6. So it might be a good idea to uninstall a previous version of Xamarin Studio on Windows if it's there.
2. This is a good point. It's something that might need a small papercut bug filed. Feel free to log an issue here and I can coordinate the status: (https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=Visual%20Studio%20Extensions). In the past I've seen a couple ways around this. 1) Make a seperate `.sln` that might be called `.Windows` which will only load Windows native projects (Android, UWP, etc). This way the step is skipped completely. 2) You can simply unload the iOS project until you need to reload the project and work on the iOS side. However I do agree there should be a project property/IDE setting that should say "Start Xamarin Mac Agent on Startup".
3. That error is really vague. We would need to gather some logs(log files can be gathered from `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Xamarin\Log` or using `Help->Xamarin`). `This operation could not be completed` typically has an error/exception following it like `This operation could not be completed: Invalid Pointer`. So we would need to dig into logs here and see if we can get a Stack Trace when it happens. I would also try deleting your `.suo` in the `.vs` hidden folder of your project directory.

Comment: Sorry -- (1) should have read "Xamarin for Visual Studio". Again, the problem isn't so much the false positive. The problem is the lockup time.